# Are all $k$-regular graphs $k+1$-partite with sets of almost equal size?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices. Is it true that we can find a partition the vertex set of $G$ into $k+1$ sets of roughly equal size (each of size at least $\lfloor \frac{n}{k+1} \rfloor$) such that each set is an independent set? If not, is it possible to partition it into a constant number of independent sets of roughly equal size?

The claim is trivially true for $1$-regular graphs, and also seems to be true for $2$-regular graphs.

Comment: The chromatic number of a $k$ regular graph is at most $k+1$ so surely, you can partition it into $k+1$ independent sets.

Comment: For $2$-regular graphs (which in fact are uniouns of disjoint cycles) the claim is true and can be easily proved by induction by the number of cycles.

Comment: If you will not obtain an answer at MSE then you may ask your question at MathOverflow with additional tags: 'reference-request' and 'discrepancy-theory'